# Fireblocks Polygon Wallet Creation Axios Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, blockchain, fireblocks-sdk, fireblocks-api

According to Fireblocks Docs , I created default wallet "BTC_TEST" like this.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X8MF.png)
But when I create Matic wallet it give me Axios Error.
I don't know the reason about that. Matic is supported assetsID in Fireblocks. Help me.
I uploaded Code and Error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80cg7.png)
Error:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdLEM.png)

Why BTC_TEST created why not MATIC

Comment: Hi, please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417)

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to bump this old questions, but incase anyone else comes looking.
I suspect you have a testnet account which is why `BTC_TEST` works and `MATIC` does not.
You should add `MATIC_TEST` (Mumbai) instead.